# Pass a variable inside translation string in Prestashop

Tags: smarty, translation, prestashop

I need to pass a variable with a translation string in Prestashop. In the Backend It is possible to do like

```
sprintf($this->l('The number is %1$d'), $number);
```

But I need to do this in the front-end while using SMARTY ? is anyone there to help me ?

Answer (score 7):

something like this :

```
{l s='The number is %1$d' sprintf=$number}
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - On PrestShop v1.7.4 with @skiplecariboo answer `{l s='The number is %1$d' sprintf=$number}` I'm getting:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   PrestaShopBundle\Translation\TranslatorComponent::trans() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   /vagrant/httpdocs/config/smartyfront.config.inc.php on line 210 and
>   defined

2 - With [official 3rd party module translation method](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-translation/) `{l s='The number is %1$d' sprintf=$number mod='my_module'}`, I'm getting the same error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   PrestaShopBundle\Translation\TranslatorComponent::trans() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   /vagrant/httpdocs/config/smartyfront.config.inc.php on line 210 and
>   defined

3 - And with [official native module translation method](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/native-module-translation/) `{l s='The number is %1$d' sprintf=$number d='Modules.my_module'}`, I'm getting:

> Unable to translate "The number is %1$d" in
>   module:my_module/my_module.tpl. sprintf() parameter should be an
>   array.

So, solution for me was to set `$number` variable as an array:

`{l s='The number is %1$d' sprintf=[$number] mod='my_module'}`

NB: `%1$d` flag is for decimal, for a string, use: `%1$s` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field))

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can passe a variable in the translated string

```
{l s='Comment: # %id%' mod='ayalinecomments' sprintf=['%id%' => $comment.id_ayalinecomments_comment]}
```

prestashop will replace %id% by my variable $comment.id_ayalinecomments_comment

ty